# Pyglet file name "Resource not found"

Tags: python, tkinter, pyglet

I'm trying to open a music track and add it to a queue for a player in Pyglet.

```
    def QueueAudio(self):
        self.musicpath=filedialog.askopenfilename()
        print(self.musicpath)
        Player.queue(pyglet.resource.media(r"self.musicpath"))
```

The musicpath variable works fine as the print statement prints the filename. The error comes when the player tries to queue the track. Error below.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pyglet\resource.py", line 605, in media
    location = self._index[name]
KeyError: 'self.musicpath'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Rob\Google Drive\Coursework\Part 2\music player tests\test5.py", line 99, in QueueAudio
    self.playerpath=pyglet.resource.media(r"self.musicpath")
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pyglet\resource.py", line 615, in media
    raise ResourceNotFoundException(name)
pyglet.resource.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource "self.musicpath" was not found on the path.  Ensure that the filename has the correct captialisation.
```

Does anyone know why this is, and what may fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This line looks to be the culprit:

```
self.playerpath=pyglet.resource.media(r"self.musicpath")
```

You are passing a string `"self.musicpath"` to a function, when you should be passing in the contents of a variable named `self.musicpath`. You need to call it like this:

```
self.playerpath = pyglet.resource.media(self.musicpath)
```

Comment: This is _definitely_ part of the problem, no question about it. If you are still getting *an* error, you can't possibly be getting the *same* exact error (unless, from the file dialog, you picked a file literally named `"self.musicpath"`). The new error should at least include the name of the file you picked. You might want to add the new code and new error message to your question, to show the research that you've done to this point.